# How to set global preferences for eclipse in multiuser environment?

Tags: linux, eclipse, configuration

We will be using eclipse(Helios or Indigo) for multiuser environment for development. For this we are working on configuring the eclipse. We have installed the plug-ins Rational Clearcase MVFS Support and Rational Clearcase SCM Adapter.

The users must enable the Rational Clearcase MVFS Support option and the Clearcase SCM Adapter auto-connection option once *per workspace* through preferences.

So my requirement, is there any way to set these preferences(or options) only one time globally so that everyone automatically gets those settings while creating their workspaces ?

If not this, is there any another way to achieve my requirement?

Appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Workspace Mechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/).  It says you can use it to "Create a consistent environment among groups as large as the entire company, your local team, or even among your own many workspaces"

Comment: Paul,thanks much for quick reply. I went through Workspace Mechanic before. This plug-in gives the options to the users. what I wanted is, there should be a default behavior of eclipse such a way that all my preferences are set for all workspaces of all users. So is there any other way like configuring or setting properties in eclipse.in or plugin_customization.ini etc.?Thanks in advance!

Comment: They explain how to do that in http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/wiki/EnterpriseConfiguration